# orderBy on ng-repeat is not working despite data being an array

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

In html

```
<div ng-controller="homeCtrl as home">
<a class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="e in home.events | orderBy:'popularity'"> {{ e.name }}</a>
</div>
```

In the controller

```
var vm = this;

vm.events = [{
            "name": "one",
            "popularity": 1
        }, {
            "name": "four",
            "popularity": 4
        }, {
            "name": "two",
            "popularity": 2
        }];
```

I get this error https://docs.angularjs.org/error/orderBy/notarray?p0=%7B%7D

Comment: you're using `home.events` in your repeat, but `vm` in your controller.. are you using something like `controllerAs:home` somewhere else? or should your repeat be using `vm.events`?

Comment: The ng-repeat works, but as soon as I add the orderBy it gives me that error.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using **`Controller As`** syntax in view

```
 <div ng-controller="ListCtrl as home">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.events = [{
      "name": "one",
      "popularity": 1
    }, {
      "name": "four",
      "popularity": 4
    }, {
      "name": "two",
      "popularity": 2
    }];
  }

]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl as home">
  <a class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="e in home.events | orderBy:'popularity'"> 
  {{ e.name }}</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had that syntax but I forgot to add it. Sorry not the fix I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the `controllerAs` syntax:

Take a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/adel_mehrban/ogrvmx61/1/

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had

```
vm.events = {};
```

before the function was called and I corrected it to

```
vm.events = [];
```

and it fixed it.

Thanks for the answers. Sorry my question didnt quite have all my code :/